# Confused about deplyoing application on openshift server using git

Tags: php, git, openshift

I am using openshift server to host my php application. I have added files to my server using sftp to ~/app-root/runtime/repo directory. The same files are accesible over the web. But when I git clone my repository to my local machine I don't see my uploaded files in it. Neither when I add and push files using git are seen in my app-root folder. Any help is kindly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes made directly on the gear's repo/ dir are not tracked by git, and will be overwritten when you push your local git repo to the gear.  To track them, scp/sftp them back to your local git repo and add/commit/push them across.

The alternative to scp/sftp is to run "rhc snapshot {appName}" which will take a backup of all your files (code and data in case of snapshot), then you can extract the files under the repo/ dir back to your local git repo, and add/commit/push them across.

Feel free to post to our forums:  https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift

Comment: Is it possible that when I push the files through git the same can be accesible over the web. Means suppose i change index.php and push it using git the same will be reflected when i visit my site.

Comment: Yes, this is how OpenShift deploying works. See https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/deploying-and-building-applications for more information.

Comment: I'm trying this out today.  The current command is `rch snapshot-save <appName>`